# How to execute a range expression for delete command in Pymol?

Tags: pymol

I am using **PyMol** and as of now I have to write a long command to delete useless files after splitting states:

```
split_states posesD01;

delete posesD01_0002;delete posesD01_0003;delete posesD01_0004;delete posesD01_0005;delete posesD01_0006;delete posesD01_0007;delete posesD01_0008;delete posesD01_0009;
```

I want to **avoid deleting** posesD01_000**1**

I have tried reducing it using regular expressions to:

```
split_states posesD01;

delete posesD01_000[2-9];
```

But it doesn't do anything. It does not throw any errors but it also does not do anything.

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thank You for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PyMOL prompt accepts wildcards (`*`). If that fits you, it would be the easiest approach.

```
delete posesD01_000*
```

For a more fine-tuned selection of numbers a pure python loop can be used.

```
for i in range(2, 10): cmd.delete(f"posesD01_000{i}")
```

To take care of leading zeros (in the case of a wider range), a explicit formatting must be set.

```
for i in range(0, 50): cmd.delete(f"posesD01_00{i:02d}")
```

By the way, you don't need to write a semicolon at the end of each command. This is python! :)

Comment: Thank You! I added the semicolon because I wanted to enter all the commands in one go into the CLI inside pymol and this made it work :)